# Is Plex only for media?

Tags: file-server

I manage a small community organisation with 10 members. We use Google Drive to share files but occasionally run up against our storage limit. Some of the files are mp3 but most are doc, pdf and xlxs which our members share, edit and update.

We have 100s of files which range in size up to about 5 mb.

We're looking for an alternative to Google Drive where we can cost effectively increase our storage without having to pay more or to periodically transfer files to an external drive when we run out of space. Ideally, we'd like our members to access files through a 'file explorer'- like interface similar to what can be done on Google Drive.

Plex looks like it would be a good solution but all of the references that I can find refer to it being a media server.

So can Plex be used as a server for sharing non-media file or is it only for media content? If only for media files, eare there other options?

Comment: Instead of asking if Plex does X, Y or Z, you might be better off listing what you want to do and asking for software suggestions to accomplish that.

Comment: I think you are better off with a NAS box.  Before I can recommend a solution, you need to specify the device and OS that your members are using.  Are they all mobiles or  a mixture of mobile and desktop ?

Comment: Thanks Rohit. A few of the committee members use Macs with the rest using Win10 or 11. I think a NAS is probably the way to go as we will need a good amount of expandable storage. Re comment by @Eric, just the usual stuff people do with Word, PDF and Excel files. Suggestions for other solutions other than Plex are appreciated as was requested in my original post.

Comment: Plex is only for media, based on your description it looks like Nextcloud could server your needs.